# How to handle intent condition in android?

Tags: android

I am sending some values from Class A to class B via

```
intent.putExtraString("tag1",value1);
```

In Class B, I am accepting those values by

```
String value1=getintent.getString("tag1");
```

From Class B I am going to Class C via intent. Then when coming back to Class B from Class C it gives me null pointer exception for value.

**My question is:** How to retain the value in this filed value1. so that when I come to Class B from C the value in value1 should still be retained. (Also kindly suggest me some solution without using static field for value1).

Comment: Can you be more specific than 'class'? Are we talking about broadcast receivers or activites? Packaged intent values are a great way to pass primitives between system components, but a static solution (in memory, or settingsfile) is always going to be better for foundation level classes. I know that isn't what you wanted to hear, so this isnt an answer.

Comment: Format your code please.

Comment: yes off course it will give you null pointer, because you are again try to get values from intent which is not there i case from C -- > B

Comment: post your code also so we can have better look

Comment: you can finish class c instead of calling class b else store value in preferences

Comment: @IftikarUrrhmanKhan you are rite but i am setting these values in the textfield and hence when moving from Activity C to B the fields are showing null.Isnt there a way where we can retain the values in the textfield when moving from activity B to C and back to B.

Comment: Better use Shared Preferences rather than passing values in Intent

Comment: you can save values in shared preference

Comment: @Nargis isnt there any other way apart from shared preferences?Like in storing values in Bundles of onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState).

Comment: @joy if you are talking about other way you can better look http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: SharedPreferences is the best solution on your case.  And it's easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

First you create a static class with a static variable , from the class A assign the data to global variable then call the class B without passing data through intent, In class B get data from the global variable and use it, then go to class C , when you come back to class B you will get data from Global variable. This is a type of design pattern in java

Answer (score 0):

DO this. You pass the intent from A -> B and you receive it in B. Now from B. you pass the same intent (key,value) pair to C. So when you come back from C, you will not get null pointer exception. This is the simplest way to do. Not the best practice.

You should use `SharedPreferences`, instead. Don't hesitate, if you don't know more about using `SharedPreferences`. Its much easy to understand.